# Телеграм-бот на python ищет в гугл таблице сообщение от пользователя и выдает обратно всю строку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, таблицы

Всем привет! Пишу телеграм-бота (на python, использую pyTelegrambotapi) и никак не могу придумать часть кода. Задача: пользователь вводит название лекарства, происходит поиск в гугл таблице этого лекарства, и в ответ бот присылает целую строку.
Пример:
-сообщение от пользователя: анальгин;
-ответ от бота: Наименование: анальгин
Годен до: 01.01.2000
Количество: 2

На данный момент код такой:

```
import telebot
import gspread

bot_token = 'Токен моего бота'
googlesheet_id = 'ID гугл таблицы'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='Наименование json файла')
sh = gc.open('Название моей таблицы')
wks = sh.worksheet('sheet1')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,
                 "Привет, я буду записывать ваши лекарства в таблицу. Введите лекарство через дефис в виде НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ-ЗАБОЛЕВАНИЕ-СРОК ГОДНОСТИ-КОЛИЧЕСТВО:")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    try:
        title, illness, expire, quantity = message.text.split("-", 3)
        text_message = f'В таблицу добавлена запись'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text_message)
        sh = gc.open('название моей таблицы')
        wks.append_row([title, illness, expire, quantity])
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ОШИБКА! Неправильный формат данных!')

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите лекарство через дефис в виде НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ-ЗАБОЛЕВАНИЕ-СРОК ГОДНОСТИ-КОЛИЧЕСТВО:')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Что конкретно вы не можете?

Comment: Написать такой код

Comment: Это не конкретика. Что у вас есть на данный момент? Если ничего то стоит хотя бы глянуть как делать этих самых ботов

Comment: На данный момент у меня есть бот, гугл таблица и код, который позволяет добавлять текст в таблицу. Осталась вот эта часть.

Comment: Ну так думаю стоит часть кода добавить в вопрос

Comment: Можете полностью готовый скрипт написать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С библиотекой telebot не работал, но могу показать пример для aiogram:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def search(message: types.Message):
    try:
        search_cell = wks.find(message.text)
        list = wks.row_values(search_cell.row)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Наименование: %s\nГоден до: %s\nКоличество: %s" % (list[0], list[1], list[2]))
    except:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'В таблице {message.text} не найдено!')
```

так выглядит Лист в google таблице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а это результат вывода в Telegram:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]